# How do I read RSS feed using GWT and GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, rss

I want to make an app that uses Google Web Toolkit and Google App Engine(Java) to read RSS feed.  How do I do this?  Do you have any examples?

I need to retrieve first 100 strings from the RSS URL.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Inspecting an RSS feed is as easy as fetching the URL and parsing its XML. Displaying it is another matter, but how do you want to display it? Be more specific in your question.

Comment: i need to retrieve first 100 string from the rss url , how do i do it , how exactly fetch URl and parse XML

Comment: There are a few libraries to accomplish this listed at http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries -- I'm not sure which if any will run on App Engine

Comment: i can see the path , its saying python .

Comment: That link is for the python GAE, not the Java one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a GWT service with a method like:

```
List<String> getRssEntries();
```

In the implementation of that service, use GAE's [java.net.URLConnection](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html) system to get the raw XML from the RSS url. Next, you'll need to parse that XML. You can use a plain XML parser, or use an RSS parser like [Rome](https://rome.dev.java.net/).

At that point, you've got all the data in your service, and you just need to pull out the info you want, put it into the `List<String>`, and return it to the browser.